# How do I access this element in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get to a link from the immediate search drop down menu. For example, when I type "AA", I want the first option, but I can't seem to get the HTML id, and therefore am unable to click it. How can I access this result, using Selenium?

[Screenshot of search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kqOd.jpg)

The website is: https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html

Comment: have you tried using the `xpath` or `css_selector`?

Answer (score 0):

I have also started searching in the DOM in the first place but didn't find anything related to the hint box. Then I went to the "Chrome Dev tool - Network tab" to see the server response. There I found they are generating some response then I went into that javascript code and found these CSS selectors/Class name selector. Which I used to extract text and find the first element and click on it.

Hope this will help.

Please try below code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html")

SearchBox = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='company']")))
action.move_to_element(SearchBox).click().send_keys('AA').perform()

# Wait till the results with hint populated (I think with the help of javascript they are doing)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.smart-search-entity-hints')))

# This will print all the List items from the hint box
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.smart-search-entity-hints').text)

# To find the first item to click i have used 'find_elements_by_class_name' you can also use
# find_elements_by_class_name to get a item collection (Have not tested it..)

driver.find_element_by_class_name('smart-search-selected-hint').click()
```